# Erro ao criar coluna em dataset Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Olá,

Estou criando um projeto em python usando Pandas e desejo criar uma coluna cujos valores são a coluna Closed - Open, mas ocorre um erro que não consigo resolver.

Meu código:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv(r'Documents\Projeto\PETR4.csv', sep=',')
dataset['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date'])
dataset['Variation'] = dataset['Close'].sub(dataset['Open'])
```

O Erro:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-309e31139274> in <module>()
----> 1 dataset['Variation'] = dataset['Close'].sub(dataset['Open'])

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in flex_wrapper(self, other, level, fill_value, axis)
   1049             self._get_axis_number(axis)
   1050         if isinstance(other, ABCSeries):
-> 1051             return self._binop(other, op, level=level, fill_value=fill_value)
   1052         elif isinstance(other, (np.ndarray, list, tuple)):
   1053             if len(other) != len(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _binop(self, other, func, level, fill_value)
   1598 
   1599         with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 1600             result = func(this_vals, other_vals)
   1601         name = _maybe_match_name(self, other)
   1602         result = self._constructor(result, index=new_index, name=name)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Exemplo de linhas da tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conseguem me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Podes colocar umas linhas de exemplo do conteudo do PETR4.csv sff?

Comment: Editei e coloquei algumas linhas.

Comment: Como imagens não ajuda nada, faz com que tenhamos de copiar à mão para conseguir ver a solução... Vou tentar ajudar mesmo assim. Talvez fazendo, `pd.read_csv(r'Documents\Projeto\PETR4.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=['Date'])`

Comment: Desculpe, não sabia que gostaria dos dados em si. Então, o problema é entre as colunas Open e Close e não Date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você provavelmente baixou esses dados do Yahoo Finance. Fiz o mesmo e aqui estão:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2010-01-04,36.950001,37.320000,36.820000,37.320000,33.627335,13303600
2010-01-05,37.380001,37.430000,36.799999,37.000000,33.339001,21396400
2010-01-06,36.799999,37.500000,36.799999,37.500000,33.789528,18720600
2010-01-07,37.270000,37.450001,37.070000,37.150002,33.474155,10964600
2010-01-08,37.160000,37.389999,36.860001,36.950001,33.293945,14624200
```

A mensagem de erro diz que o erro é acontece porque essas variáveis foram lidas como string:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Estou quase certo de que o problema é que o pandas está interpretando suas variáveis numéricas (`Open`,`Close`,etc) como strings porque o separador de decimal deve estar mal especificado ou por conta de algum outro erro (NA, algum traço, etc). Isso porque sua variável `Volume` não parece estar como numérica.

Se for algum erro na base você tem que procurar. Porque eu baixei o csv do Yahoo Finance da PETR4 para todo o ano de 2010 e não deu problema.

Mas o jeito mais fácil de resolver isso é usando a opção `decimal`. Supondo que ele é ponto '.' e não vírgula ',' você deve escrever:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(r'Documents\Projeto\PETR4.csv', sep=',', decimal='.')
```

Se não for suficiente defina também o separador de milhar usando `thousands = ','` ou modo apropriado ao que aparece no csv.

Se ainda assim não der certo, você pode tentar outras opções:

- `dtype = {'Open': np.float64, 'Close': np.float64}`
- `converters` , você pode passar um dicionário de funções que limpam as variáveis dependendo do caso

**Observação**
Normalmente o que se usa como variação de preços é a diferença do preço de fechamento atual com o preço de fechamento do período anterior. Se for este o seu caso, você pode fazer

- Para calcular a taxa de retorno diária:

  `dataset['Variation'] = dataset['Close'].pct_change()`
- Para o retorno diário (em reais):

  `dataset['Variation'] = dataset['Close'].sub(dataset['Close'].shift(1))`

Comment: Cara, era exatamente isso. Muito obrigado!